# Looping through JQuery to get a specific index of a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a HTML page rendered by jquery from an json array, each page displayed is the index of an obeject of the array. e.g Page 1 displays all the data in object[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdkHn.png) of the array and Page 2 for object[2], I have an approve button for each page and i want to be able to change the status field in each json object of the array when I click the approve button depending on the page I am currently on.

```
if (canEdit === true) {
    var editDelete = '<div class="row"><div class="span6"><a id="title_edit" href="#kate" class="btn btn-small bind-edit disabled">' + gettext("edit") + '</a>&nbsp;<a href="#"class="btn btn-small btn-danger">' + gettext("Delete") + '</a></div></div>';
    var approve = '<div style="margin-top:5%;" class="row"><div class="span6"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#approve" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">'+ gettext("approve") + '</a>'
    dataContainer.append(editDelete);
    dataContainer.append(approve);
}
```

The approve variable is rendering the approve button on the page.

```
<div id="approve" class="modal fade" >
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to aprrove this record. If you are unsure about deleting this record press
            'Cancel'.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="approve" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Approve</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The approve button then triggers this modal for approve confirmation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var x = 0;
$('#approve').click(function () {

$.getJSON(mongoAPIUrl).success(function (data) {
console.log(data);


}).error(function () {
console.log('error');

})
});
});
```

This is suppose to get the data from the api, currently it fetches the data but I want it to fetch the specific object index depending on the page number.

[image: This is how the page looks like, the approve button should be able to send a POST request to the json index for just that page.]

Comment: "i want to be able to change the status field in each json object of the array when I click the approve button" and "I want it to fetch the specific object index depending on the page number."...there are two different requirements here, it's not clear if they are aspects of the same thing or if they contradict each other - there's not quite enough context about your application to be certain. Please be clear about what you want to do

Comment: Anyway, how do you expect us to tell you what to do with your JSON if we can't see it? We also know nothing about your server - does it accept search parameters to filter the data, or are you intending to download the whole lot and then filter it in your browser? If you do intend to over-write the data, how does your server allow you to save data back again? Do you have to save the whole object, or can you save single items from it? Lots of missing info about your app. The question is vague, unclear and potentially a bit too wide-ranging. If you edit it (a lot) we might be able to help more.